# Angular 2 directive isn't changing the templates elements upon first router redirect only upon reload

Tags: angular, router

I have header and footer as separate angular components. When user is logged out, on the header I display only logo and and "sign in" div but when a user is logged in I dynamically add elements to header  and it is done in header template via custom directive. 
So when logging in and redirecting from localhost:4200/signin to localhost:4200/profile I want elements on header component to be added but it did not happen upon first redirect but only when I reload localhost:4200/profile as logged in user.

**Part of the directive:**

```
  condition: boolean;


  ngOnInit() {
    const isAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated) => {
        if (isAuthenticated && this.condition || !isAuthenticated && !this.condition ) { 
           this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
          this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
      }
    );

    }


  @Input() set showAuthed(condition: boolean) {
    this.condition = condition;
  }

}

**Part of header template: showAuthed - directive **

<div class="menu">



    <div class="logo-place">
      <img routerLink="/" class="logo" src="../assets/logo-colored.svg" width="150px" height="28px"> </div>

    <div class="unauth" *showAuthed="false">


      <div *ngIf="routeIsActive('/register') || routeIsActive('/signup-outs') || routeIsActive('/signup-client')" class="login"
        routerLink="/signin" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" style="cursor: pointer;">
        Sign in
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="routeIsActive('/signin')" class="register" routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active" style="cursor: pointer;">
        Register
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Show this for logged in users -->
    <div class="auth" *showAuthed="true" >
```

**Here main part of auth service:**

```
var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();



@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authIsLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  authDidFail = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  authStatusChanged = new Subject<boolean>();
  registeredUser: CognitoUser;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

// USER SIGN-IN


  signIn(username: string, password: string): void {
    this.authIsLoading.next(true);
    const authData = {
      Username: username,
      Password: password
    };
    const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authData);
    const userData = {
      Username: username,
      Pool: userPool
    };
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    const that = this;
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
      onSuccess (result: CognitoUserSession) {
        that.authDidFail.next(false);
        that.authIsLoading.next(false);
        that.authStatusChanged.next(true);
        that.router.navigateByUrl('/profile', { skipLocationChange: false })


      },
      onFailure(err) {
        that.authDidFail.next(true);
        that.authIsLoading.next(false);
        console.log(err);

      }
    });

    this.authStatusChanged.next(true);  // create user with cognito data


  }


  getAuthenticatedUser() {
    return  userPool.getCurrentUser()
  }


  logout() {

    this.authStatusChanged.next(false);
    this.getAuthenticatedUser().signOut();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/signin')
  }

  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    const user = this.getAuthenticatedUser();
    const obs = Observable.create((observer) => {
      if (!user) {
        observer.next(false);
      } else {
        user.getSession((err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            observer.next(false);
          } else {
            if (session.isValid()) {
              observer.next(true);
            } else {
              observer.next(false);
            }
          }
        });
      }
      observer.complete();
    });
    return obs;
  }

  initAuth() {
    this.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
      (auth) => this.authStatusChanged.next(auth)

    );
  }


}
```

**My header component**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  showSignup: boolean;
  currentUrl : string;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;



  constructor (
    private authGuard: AuthGuard,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,


  ){} 

  ngOnInit() {

    this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
      (authenticated) => {
        if (authenticated) {
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
        } else {
          this.isAuthenticated = false;
        }

      }

    );

  }
```

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel apparently. All you need to do is to store the isAuthenticated boolean in the header component, and use *ngIf="isAuthenticated" to show of hide the various parts of the header inside its template.

Comment: the problem is just with the first redirect from signing to profile when user signing in, then if I reload localhost:4200/profile when user is authenticated -everything appears as needed. So just can't figure out how to make a header component update a template upon user signing, cause it is doing it only after reload, and as far as I understand  when NgOnInit is triggered where I check user's authentication.

Comment: Then it means the auth service doesn't emit an event as it should do after registration.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question.

Comment: The Observable returned by isAuthenticated() only emits once. So that can't possibly work. I don't have the courage to understand all you're doing in your service, but I guess that you should rather subscribe to the authStatusChanged observable, whic seems to emit every time the authentication status changes.

Comment: I've tried to subscribe to authStatusChanged but result is the same

Answer (score 0):

In  ngOnInit() I subscirbe to  this.authService.authStatusChanged.subscribe

which is emitting on every change and in ngDoCheck() subscribe to

```
this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe
```

which is emitting once

I this way I got the needed behavior